# Can I create a macro that will offer a drop down menu for subjects in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, macros

I need the subject line in my Outlook messages to begin with job the message concerns.  Since there are about a dozen jobs going on at any particular time, it's cumbersome to either type the job name in, or copy and paste from another message.  I've been working with a macro with a button on the Outlook menu that creates a new message, but right now I'm stuck with one job as the subject, and haven't figured out how to give myself a drop down menu of all the possible job names.  So, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here's the macro that I'm currently using.  I could create an individual macro for each of the jobs, but that takes up a lot of screen space.  And it would be easier to update the jobs as needed using the drop down menu.

Sub AutoSubject()
Set myFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set myItem = myFolder.Items.Add("IPM.Note.mail")
myItem.Display
With myItem
.Subject = "1209 NL Utilities"
.Display
End With
End Sub

Comment: I believe that's not possible. It's also impossible to have an auto-complete feature for the subject line in Outlook.

Comment: The html form tag... but then you wouldn't really need Outlook at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this. Be sure to have an open item when you launch.

http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=369

http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=303

```
'** The following code goes in a userform **

' Adapted for a single choice

Private Sub cmdOkay_Click()
Dim i As Long
Dim msg As String
Dim Check As String

Dim currItem As MailItem

'Generate a list of the selected items
With ListBox1
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            msg = .List(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End With

If msg = vbNullString Then
    'If nothing was selected, tell user and let them try again
    MsgBox "Nothing was selected!  Please make a selection!"
    Exit Sub

Else

    Set currItem = Application.ActiveInspector.currentItem
    currItem.Subject = msg
    Unload Me

End If

End Sub

Private Sub cmdCancel_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

With Me.ListBox1
     'Clear the rowsource in case it has been set
    .RowSource = ""
     'Add the items
    .AddItem ("Cat")
    .AddItem ("Dog")
    .AddItem ("Gerbil")
    .AddItem ("Lizard")
    .AddItem ("Rat")
    .AddItem ("Snake")
    .AddItem ("Turtle")
End With

End Sub


 '** The following code goes in a standard module **

Sub Launch()
'This code will launch the userform
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```